# SharePoint list calculated column Concatenate Function

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have Created a Date and Time column, Based on on that i have taken calculated column to concatenate Text and Date. But it is not showing Date format in calculated column. Can you please help with this.

Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(" An Ally Bank Branch"," ",Title," ","is established on",[Established Date])
```

[image]

Comment: Try this: `=CONCATENATE(" An Ally Bank Branch"," ",Title," ","is established on",TEXT([Established Date],"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

Comment: Hi @Chandrika, is below solution working for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Established Date]),"",CONCATENATE("An Ally Bank Branch"," ",Title," ","is established on: ",TEXT([Established Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

This shows text description only when date column is not blank.

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))